# Same Dockerfile and build context, different layer digests

Tags: docker, docker-build, buildx

I'm building the following Dockerfile twice using buildx. For some reason I fail to understand the layers produced from the RUN command have different digests. The two executions of the build happen within seconds on the same host (tried on both Mac Intel, Docker Engine 24.06 and Ubuntu 20.04, Docker version 24.0.7).

This is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10-slim-bullseye 

RUN sh -c "echo hello"
```

These are the commands I'm using to run the build twice:

```
docker buildx build --build-arg BUILDKIT_STEP_LOG=1 --progress plain --no-cache --tag ca-test:1 . 
docker buildx build --build-arg BUILDKIT_STEP_LOG=1 --progress plain --no-cache --tag ca-test:2 .
```

The resulting layer digests (`RootFS.Layers`) for the first build are:

```
  "sha256:74c0af6e02274b54b88f851843ae69880a234694dede8ff9fb93bfa076af45ed",
  ...
  "sha256:9647f452a52939a4807a7534ecbac34470618d7822881739b99c076862f69fdf",
  "sha256:a12f7c086f54288199c551849f2ece71758541ca02bda42793a6e8efe754b91f"
```

While for the second build, they are (note the difference in the last layer):

```
  "sha256:74c0af6e02274b54b88f851843ae69880a234694dede8ff9fb93bfa076af45ed",
  ...
  "sha256:9647f452a52939a4807a7534ecbac34470618d7822881739b99c076862f69fdf",
  "sha256:cf80db41eb34c3282f4456b0b71bab7c0521078e60cccbc01de407197dd54b6d"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Container images are content addressable and immutable, but not necessarily reproducible. Buildx is still adding features for reproducibility. At least on my environment this example is reproducible for that layer, since it's empty, but not for the image itself (which requires more flags for timestamps).

Comment: The data used for the hashes contain timestamps and other metadata that causes them to be different.

Comment: They would if there was a file in the tar. With the given run command that outputs nothing, something is different between our environments that is including a file in Roy's image but not mine (that said, I'm outputting to an OCI tar instead of the docker engine to view the contents, and that can inject some differences too).

Comment: @BMitch - my understanding is that the digest of the layer determines whether a layer can be taken from the cache. Since the two builds result in a different digest, the next statements in the docker file can’t be taken from the cache. Is that true? If so, what might be a solution?

Comment: @HansKilian - the image digest includes timestamp etc, but I’m not sure that the layer does. Using a different base image (eg alpine) does produce layers with the same digest.

Comment: @Roy2012 A similar question was asked here and answered by one of the developers: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/28665

Comment: Nothing will be taken from the cache with the `--no-cache` flag. Is this a caching question or a reproducibility question? If it's a reproducibility question, then export the image to a tar and provide the contents of the specific layer (which is a tar+gzip) that is changing. If it's a caching question, then please provide a reproducible example showing what you believe should use the cache and isn't. Note that layers do include timestamps, one for each file and directory.